# Не могу вставить символ utf-8 в HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

В интернете написано что надо вставить код символа после значения "content: ", что я собственно и сделал. Так почему же символ не появляется? (• - Жирная точка) butt_nav - Текст ссылки
Код:

```
.butt_nav::before {
content: &#8226;        
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в кавычки обернуть html код

Comment: @Inventor - непрокатит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо символы `&#` удалить и поставить обратный слеш

```css
p {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

p:after {
  content: '\8226';
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: а я просто из таблицы символов копирую и вставляю как есть)

Comment: @eri ну если просто вставить то вообще не выводится - а если вставить в html то выводится круг

Comment: именно этот у меня квадрат... что по коду вствлять, что по значению. шрифты не те. вот  и ☣ встают и так и так одинаково

Comment: @eri я так то не спорю - но я эту плюшку в html вставил - получился круглешёк - убрал `&#` и поставил в css content '\8226' получился иероглиф :))

Comment: это значит что ваш метод неточен)

Comment: @eri покажите как надо сделать -

Comment: написал ответ отдельно

Answer (score 1):

`#` тут говорит что символ в десятичной системе счисления

```
&#8226;
```

Если символ записан как `&#x2022;` через `#x` - значит он в 16-ой системе счисления

Нужно перевести в шеснадцетеричную систему и добавить `\`

```css
p {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

p:after {
  content: '\2022';
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Но мне проще скопировать сам символ из таблицы и вставить как есть

```css
p {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

p:after {
  content: '•';
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: так у вас же не 8226

Comment: добавьте 8226 и будет ответ дубликат

Comment: `&#8226;` = `&#x2022;` = `'\2022'` = `•` = `&bull;`

Comment: `\8226` - это не правильный ответ) поэтому я его и не пишу

Comment: это как вы получили 8226 = 2022 ?

Comment: перевод из десятичной в 16-ую систему счисления

Comment: ладно - автору виднее

Comment: да это точно `&bull;` а не иероглиф )

Comment: какое то совпадение - то ли bull то ли иероглиф

Comment: иксика нет чтоб быть иероглифом)

Comment: а почему тогда убрать `&#` получается иероглиф ?

Comment: потому что это неправильно

Comment: автору виднее...

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то ещё интересно - в HTML разметке используется десятеричное число в формате **&#8226**. В CSS - шестнадцатиричное, в формате **\2022**. Оба числа равны, разная система счисления.